# Others and The others

Tags: definite-articles

In an IQ test, I was presented with these two sentences followed by a question. I've highlighted the difference between the sentences.

> **A:** Some of the boys in the party on Thursday wore black suits. **Others** wore blue suits.
>
> **B:** Some of the boys in the party on Sunday wore blue suits. **The others** wore black suits.
>
> **Question:** Sam wore a dark blue suit to the party. Which day did he attend the party?

Presumably the definite article *the* makes a difference to how we can determine which group Sam falls into and which day he partied.

But I don't understand what the difference is. How does *the* allow us to determine the answer to the question?

Comment: I'm voting to migrate to [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). Mahdi - by including the article, ***the** others* implies ***all** the others*. But your "IQ Test" looks pretty dumb to me, since Sam could have gone in a black suit on *either* day. Are you sure you transcribed it correctly? If Sam had worn a ***green*** suit, for example, we could safely say he must have gone on Thursday,

Comment: @FumbleFingers Sam wore a *dark blue* suit, not a black one.

Comment: it was not an IQ Test, Andrew leach edited my question, so... (-: the question was some odd. so we called it IQ Test in our class. and thanks for  English Language Learners. i didn't know about that.

Comment: The principal problem with this is that a dark blue suit is still a blue one. And Mahdi, your [original version](http://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/367093/1) mentioned the IQ test.

Comment: "!!!" these "!"s means that its a joke for us. forget that. i got the answer. thanks.

Comment: @Glorfindel: My mistake. I meant to say Sam could have worn a *dark blue* suit on either day (as Andrew says, dark blue is still *blue*). On Thursday he'd be one of the "**others**", whereas on Sunday he'd be included in "**some** of the boys". But he couldn't have worn a suit colour that's *not* specified (such as ***green***) on Sunday. because we know ***everyone*** wore either black or blue on that day. Unspecified colours could only be worn on Thursday, when it's pragmatically implied that "some" + "others" doesn't cover everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Whether a dark-blue suit is also considered a blue suit is one question. Maybe, maybe not. Depends on what is meant by a color, here.

But the main point/question here should be that unqualified *others* means ***some*** others, whereas *the others* means ***all*** others (as @Glorfindel said).

So **IF** dark-blue is considered blue **THEN** Sam could have attended either Thursday or Sunday.

But **IF** dark-blue is considered to be a **different** color from blue (as well as different from black) **THEN** Sam could only have attended Thursday, since on Sunday the only colors worn were blue and black, not dark-blue.